# keyboard settings changed with right ctr key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

so I have no idea what happened. I am using 20.04 ubuntu lts and updated it I think (over software updater) and when I wanted to type square brackets, I realized that instead "1/2" is given out.

I already resetted the keyboard with sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration but that didnt help.

without being able to use square brackets in programming I feel really fcked so to say.

Can someone help me?

Best, medskillz

Comment: what's the output of `setxkbmap -query` in terminal?

Answer (score 1):

open the settings after that open keyboard..customize shorcuts and change the settings

Comment: didnt help but realized that its just the difference to mac keyboard again. dunno why I felt it changed suddenly. - but thanks!!